# Metamaterial with index of refraction different in opposite directions

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, birefringence, metamaterials

Has anyone created a mathematical model for a material whose index of refraction is different going right than it is for light traveling to the left?

Comment: This sounds like magnetic birefringence for circularly polarized light. Silverman has written about it.

Comment: Your material breaks time symmetry. Physics don't like that. Worse, I believe you can use the material to convert thermal energy into something useful. Physics like that even less.

Comment: So... what should happen if a beam of light undergoes total internal reflection inside your material?

Comment: If you apply a magnetic field, you can get non-reciprocal propagation of light, because this breaks the time-reversal symmetry.  See [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/20/33/335217) for instance.  I don't think you can get this with just material properties however; the application of the external magnetic field is crucial, as I understand it.

Comment: @John Dvorak, can you please explain how the material breaks 2nd law?

Comment: @Astik With a time-asymmetric you can place a lens in the vicinity of two equally warm objects such that one sees the other, and gets heated by its blackbody radiation, but not vice versa. Not a Maxwell's demon, though, I concede. Now, if you can break conservation of etendue using multiple reflections, you get Maxwell's demon for free. My idea is to use a plane mirror on one side (which squeezes the beam as it enters the high-IoR direction) and a retroreflective mirror to send it back in the same direction, but that breaks if you can't construct a retroreflector that doesn't disperse the beam

Comment: My understanding is that the refractive index depends on a material, but not on propagation direction of light. The behavior of light can change depending on the direction (non-reciprocal propagation ), but the RI is fixed by a material.